# Shelled root seems to print incorrect from /etc/shadow | grep root

Tags: 16.04, command-line, scripts, ssh, python3

I'm trying to understand why my script prints `cat /etc/shadow | grep root` as the empty string `('')`. This happens even though my script gets access to `root@127.0.0.1`...

I'm walking my way through Violent Python and am creating a simple SSH worm.

When I'm running the above command I can see my encrypted password, both as `root@127.0.0.1` and with `sudo`. So clearly the command works.

Is there something I'm missing here? Some sort of special circumstances I'm missing?

Here is the script:

```
import pexpect

PROMPT = ['#', '>>>', '>', '\$']

def send_command(child, cmd):
    child.sendline(cmd)
    child.expect(PROMPT)
    print(child.before)

def connect(user, host, password):
    ssh_newkey = 'Are you sure you want to continue connecting'
    strcon = 'ssh ' + user + '@' + host
    child = pexpect.spawn(strcon)

    ret = child.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT, ssh_newkey,\
                        '[P|p]assword:'])

    if ret == 0:
        print('[-] Error connecting')
        return

    if ret == 1:
        child.sendline('yes')
        ret = child.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT,\
                            '[P|p]assword:'])
        if ret == 0:
            print('[-] Error Connecting...')
            return
        child.sendline(password)
        child.expect(PROMPT)
        return child

    child.sendline(password)
    child.expect(PROMPT)
    return child

def main():
    host = 'localhost'
    user = 'root'
    password = 'toor'
    child = connect(user, host, password)
    send_command(child, 'cat /etc/shadow | grep root')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: CAT ABUSE !!!! No need to pipe cat to grep, just grep `grep root /etc/shadow` - http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r21664624-Do-You-Abuse-the-cat

Comment: First off, thanks for pointing that out. I'm not a great at using Linux. Second, that didn't do anything to solve my problem.

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong bu my guess is you need to run the command over ssh. `ssh root@localhost 'grep root /etc/shadow'`

Answer (score 0):

OK, so in this case it would seem as if it all boiled down to the `child.before` print in `send_command`.

Printing out the `child` object I could see that there were a few key-value pairs that I should have grabbed, one of which (`buffer`) holds the 100 last characters of the `grep`. This isn't the full encrypted password, but at least some of them.

So, if you do find yourself in a similar problem simply print the `child` and check what the output is!